# Get the first x lines of a File

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to get the first 10 lines from a file into a string and write them to another file.

I've got:

```
File.open("read_file.txt", "r") do |rf|
  File.open("write.txt", "w") do |wf|
    rf.each_line.with_index do |line, idx|
      break if idx > 9
      wf.puts(line)
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a more elegant and efficient way to break on a specified number of lines

Ideally something like `file.lines(3) : String` would be nice but that certainly isn't available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a more elegant way (but with the same efficiency, I believe)

```
File.open "read_file.txt" do |io|
  File.write "write.txt", io.each_line.first(10).join("\n")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the lines of the file with [`File#read_lines`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.26.1/File.html#read_lines%28filename%2Cencoding%3Dnil%2Cinvalid%3Dnil%2Cchomp%3Dtrue%29%3AArray%28String%29-class-method) and then take the first 10 lines:

```
File.read_lines("file")[0..9]
```

Comment: `File#read_lines` Returns all lines in filename as an array of strings.

This is certainly very inefficient for large files.